# Generics array cast

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I've got the following code:

```
public class GenericsTest<T> {

        private T[] array1;
        private String[] array2;

        public GenericsTest() {
            array1 = (T[]) new Object[10];
            array2 = (String[]) new Object[10];
        }

        public T[] getArray1() {
            return array1;
        }

        public void setArray1(T[] array1) {
            this.array1 = array1;
        }

        public String[] getArray2() {
            return array2;
        }

        public void setArray2(String[] array2) {
            this.array2 = array2;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new GenericsTest<String>();
        }

    }
```

Code crushes at line:

```
array2 = (String[]) new Object[10];
```

But it works fine with:

```
array1 = (T[]) new Object[10];
```

As you can see in `main()` method, `T` is a `String`. So I guess compiler will change T to String in

```
private T[] array1;
```

and `array1 = (T[]) new Object[10]` 
will be translated to 
`array1 = (String[]) new Object[10]`

So why 
`array2 = (String[]) new Object[10]` 
fails and `(T[]) new Object[10]`
doesn't?

Comment: I do not see the point of using parameterized type T if you know it is always String

Comment: I don't think you can cast a Object[] into a String[], why not just make array2 to new String[] instead of an Object[]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Comment: So since you are testing, String is immutable but you have also options like GenericsTest<T extends String> or GenericsTest<T super String>

Comment: This code emits compiler warnings for a reason.  Generics are not compatible with arrays;  always use Lists (or at least Collections) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because generic types will be lost after compilation, and all your generic `<T>` will be transformed into `Object`, so, when you do

```
(T[]) new Object[10];
```

it is equal to

```
(Object[]) new Object[10];
```

And of course it is not equal to

```
(String[]) new Object[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic type `T` is a generic **Object** type, and can be cast to an `Object` so like: `(Object[]) new Object[10])`

Meanwhile `String` extends `Object` and so you cannot cast upwards.